# Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.ProductInstallation.AllProducts alternative in .NET Core

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, wix, windows-installer

We were using `ProductInstallation.AllProducts` to check if a product is installed on Windows:

```
public static bool isProductInstalled(string productCode) {
            ProductInstallation instProd = ProductInstallation.AllProducts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductCode == productCode);
            return (instProd != null && instProd.IsInstalled);
        }
```

Is there any alternative to it in .NET Core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep using DTF libraries with .NET Core on Windows.

Comment: How? which package should I use?

Comment: Reference the dll, just like .NET Framework projects.